# CitrusFramework - Cannot run through cucumber java

Tags: java, rest, api, cucumber-java, citrus-framework

i was trying to create a Citrus API framework for REST and SOAP calls using cucumber. After creating all classes and features required and i came to run the runner class, while running the runnerclass am getting error saying `Unrecognized plugin: com.consol.citrus.cucumber.CitrusReporter`
full error will be attached below.

My Runner class is in `com.consol.citrus.demo.voting.rest` package

```
package com.consol.citrus.Petstore.rest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = { "com.consol.citrus.Petstore.rest",
                 "com.consol.citrus.cucumber.step.runner.core",
                 "com.consol.citrus.cucumber.step.runner.http" },
plugin = { "com.consol.citrus.cucumber.CitrusReporter" })
public class PetstorerestIT {

}
```

My Stepdef in `com.consol.citrus.demo.voting.rest` Package

```
package com.consol.citrus.Petstore.rest;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import com.consol.citrus.annotations.CitrusEndpoint;
import com.consol.citrus.annotations.CitrusResource;
import com.consol.citrus.dsl.builder.HttpActionBuilder;
import com.consol.citrus.dsl.runner.TestRunner;
import com.consol.citrus.http.client.HttpClient;


import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class Petstoresteps {

    @CitrusEndpoint
    private HttpClient votingClient;

    @CitrusResource
    private TestRunner runner;


    @Given("^i set variables to configure$")
    public void i_set_variables_to_configure() throws Throwable {

            runner.variable("id", "citrus:randomUUID()");
            runner.variable("name", "ArunKumar");
            runner.variable("photoUrls", "photo.jpg");
            runner.variable("status", "available");

    }

    @Given("^i send the payload request$")
    public void i_send_the_payload_request() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

        runner.http(action -> action.client(votingClient)
                .send()
                .post("/voting")
                .contentType("application/json")
                .payload("{\r\n" + 
                        "  \"id\": \"${id}\",\r\n" + 
                        "  \"category\": {\r\n" + 
                        "    \"id\": \"${id}\",\r\n" + 
                        "    \"name\": \"${name}\"\r\n" + 
                        "  },\r\n" + 
                        "  \"name\": \"${name}\",\r\n" + 
                        "  \"photoUrls\": [\r\n" + 
                        "    \"${photoUrls}\"\r\n" + 
                        "  ],\r\n" + 
                        "  \"tags\": [\r\n" + 
                        "    {\r\n" + 
                        "      \"id\": \"${id}\",\r\n" + 
                        "      \"name\": \"${name}\"\r\n" + 
                        "    }\r\n" + 
                        "  ],\r\n" + 
                        "  \"status\": \"${status}\"\r\n" + 
                        "}"));


    }

    @And("^i check for the content type$")
    public void i_check_for_the_content_type() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        runner.http(action -> action.client(votingClient)
                .receive()
                .response().contentType("application/json"));

    }

    @Then("^receive status (\\d+) OK$")
    public void receive_status_OK(int arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

        HttpActionBuilder arg = runner.http(action -> action.client(votingClient)
                .receive()
                .response(HttpStatus.OK));
        String argg = arg.toString();
        System.out.println(argg);

    }


}
```

My CitrusEndpointConfig is in `com.consol.citrus.Petstore` Package

```
package com.consol.citrus.Petstore;

import com.consol.citrus.dsl.endpoint.CitrusEndpoints;
import com.consol.citrus.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class CitrusEndpointConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpClient votingClient() {
        return CitrusEndpoints.http()
                .client()
                .requestUrl("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2")
                .build();
    }


}
```

Error Message :

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: com.consol.citrus.cucumber.CitrusReporter
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:372)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:125)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:85)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:78)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:70)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:25)
```

Please Guide me to resolve this issue ! i need it so badly !

**Cucumber.properties:**
[image: Cucumber.properties]

**Citrus-application.properties:**

[image: Citrus-application.properties]

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the `CitrusObjectFactory` property to the `cucumber.properties` file? As per [the documentation](https://citrusframework.org/samples/cucumber/):

> In order to enable Citrus Cucumber support we need to specify a special object factory in cucumber.properties.
>
> ```
> cucumber.api.java.ObjectFactory=cucumber.runtime.java.CitrusObjectFactory
> ```
>
> The object factory takes care on creating all step definition instances. The object factory is able to inject @CitrusResource annotated fields in step classes.
>
> The usage of this special object factory is mandatory in order to combine Citrus and Cucumber capabilities.

Comment: @ELEVATE Thanks! but anyway i am facing the same issue only now also :(  "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: com.consol.citrus.cucumber.CitrusReporter
 at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:372)" above i have edited and attached the image of the properties file